# Service doesn't work properly in CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, service, countdowntimer

I am creating an app which uses a CountDownTimer.
I'd like to use a Service method to properly work a CountDownTimer in background.

But, in my implementation of code, it doesn't work properly.

Service doesn't show a text in Toast and doesn't send correctly intent to activity probably. 
Should I use this code of CountDownTimer in MyService class?
Could someone help me with this?

This is ***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    TextView textViewTime;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

        textViewTime.setText("00:01:30");

        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(90000, 1000);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timer.start();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
        }

    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            textViewTime.setText(hms);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTime.setText("Completed.");
        }
    }

    public void startService(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void stopService(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }


}
```

This is ***MyService.java***

```
public class MyService extends Service {



    @Override
    public void onCreate() { // initial performance (setup service in this method)
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  // create start a service

        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Started...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        return START_STICKY;
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {  // stop a service

        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {  
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you commented `super` methods in the Service class? Where do you start a service? startService is not called in your code.

Comment: Because I think that this method should return an integer value and STICKY command do this.
startService is called in MainActivity (almost at the end of lines)

@Vyacheslav I changed this and now is returning this super method.

Comment: first of all, always use super methods in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
startService(v);
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
stopService(v);
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: I changed this. But now, it only shows a Toast text but I don't why when I turn off this app and I go to the "Running Apps" it's closed. In manifest I have: <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:exported="false"
             ></service>
Nevertheless, this Timer still doesn't work after I clicked a back button. When I come back it's a restart of timer.

Comment: @gryzek , the count down timer doesn't work because of you have lauched it inside the activity. Try to launch in inside Service.onCreated method.

Comment: Thanks for this help. But the main second question is why it doesn't work in a background. The question is still open.

Comment: what I should launch in inside? When I put this code from MainActivity(onCreate) to MyService (onCreate) is needed to copy all timer class -> like public Counterclass etc.

Comment: @gryzek , I don't not CountDown timer managment, but all long-term are killed if they work in the background (battery life save mode for mobile devices). Use `startForeground`  or `AlarmManager` to prevent this.

Comment: @gryzek , you launch the service from `MainActivity`, then in `MyService` launch `CountDownTimer`.

Comment: I have problem with properly implementation of this. I have still errors. But I'll read about startForeground method or I can avoid this? Do you think that the only Service method can be inadequate? Thanks!

Comment: i know that if you set your service as `startForeground` your can be sure that your countdown will work anyway.